# Retrieve managed package metadata using Org Browser in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ide, visualstudiocode, org-browser

I have created a project using [**Org Browser**](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser) in visual studio code instead of creating a project using the manifest file since it eliminates the need to manually update the package.xml file and also it can automatically retrieve any new component added in the org without much manual effort.

But I'm unable to retrieve managed package components from org browser. For example, our instance has Salesforce CPQ managed package and have our custom fields and workflow rules on the Quote object (API: SBQQ__Quote__c). If I were using manifest, I could manually add the object API name to the package.xml so that the components are pulled. Is there anything similar when a project is created without manifest? I could not find any documentation around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a product limitation at the moment. There is a issue reported already on their GitHub page:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1998